# How to add Admob advertising in my Android application?

Tags: java, android, admob

I have read this article http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html, and now I have the code

```
package com.nda.admob;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class AdMobTestingActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    AdView adView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,  "a14eb6c98335a35");
        LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
        l.addView(adView);

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(request);
    }
}
```

And code for AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.nda.admob"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AdMobTestingActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>       
    </application>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

But I have the message "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges" always. Where have I made mistake?

Comment: dude, are u fixed this problem with 2.1 or 2.2 ??? i have this error too.. and i not need 3+ :(

Comment: you can run with 2.1 or 2.2 versions but you have to change your app "target=android-13"............. is 13 or 13+

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the latest admob sdk, you need define your AdActivity like this:

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Note that some configChanges option requires a later Android SDK version (API Level 11), As it is stated in the link your provided, you need:

> Requirements
>
> The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires Android 1.5 or later. Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13).

Hope that help.

Comment: Thank you. If I have Android v2.1, what should I do?

Comment: Just follow their instruction and set default.properties to android-13, don't replace your Android SDK, you will get a litte yellow warning in Eclipse says SDK version manifest and propertries not match. just ignore this and build your applicaiton, you will be OK.

Comment: I have got many red exceptions. Can you input here an example of code in shared answer? Thank you.

Comment: what is the exception? The link you provided is really everything you need in your code, I can't think anything beyond that.

Comment: If I set android-13 in default.properties, that I have got "Unable to resolve target 'android-13'" in Console and I can't set "keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" - I have error "String types not allowed".

Comment: "String types not allowed" is due to "Unable to resolve target 'android-13" using Android SDK tools download the SDK 13, if SDK 13 is not available, using SDK 14 or 15 instead.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are missing the listener.
ply try by adding this just after you init adView

```
adView.setAdListener(this);
```