# Google Play Admob integration with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, admob, google-play-services, cordova-admob

How do you add Google Admob to a phonegap app (android) in 2014?

I have checked many examples online e.g. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029520/how-to-add-admob-advertising-in-my-android-application?rq=1) [link2](https://github.com/sainttex/PhoneGap-Android-Native-AdMob) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900622/phonegap-use-play-services-for-ads) [Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002424/admob-with-cordova-3-and-google-play-services). Most link to Googles soon to be deprecated [Android 6.4.1 tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadandroid).

Apart from specific [android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSBN1OrCjGs) or iOS tutorials, **I cannot find any that demonstrate how to implement the [latest admob](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadplay) into phonegap for a cross platform app**. I have seen inmobi however it looks like you have to publish your app before you can get a publisher id for your adverts.

**Update with Android simplified instructions**
 I am getting the black box for the advert however nothing else, no alert messages, no advert

```
phonegap create myproject
cd mypproject
phonegap run android
```

Close down the emulator

```
1.Install the Google Play Services plugin:  cordova plugin add     https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/google-play-services.git  
2.Install this plugin:  cordova plugin add https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob.git
```

Then I headed over to index.js and onDeviceReady I added

```
   onDeviceReady: function() {
     app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

if( window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob ) {
    var admob_android_key = 'pub-6xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    var am = window.plugins.AdMob;

    am.createBannerView( 
    {
    'publisherId': admob_android_key,
    'adSize': am.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
    'bannerAtTop': true
    }, 
    function() {
        am.requestAd(
            { 'isTesting':true }, 
            function(){
                am.showAd( true );
            }, 
            function(){ alert('failed to request ad'); }
        );
    }, 
    function(){ alert('failed to create banner view'); }
    );
    } else {
    alert('AdMob plugin not available/ready.');
    }

  }
```

Added to index.html

```
       <div>
            <button id='show-ad' onClick="if(window.plugins.AdMob){ window.AdMob.plugins.showAd(true); }">Show Ad</button>
            <button id='hide-ad' onClick="if(window.plugins.AdMob){ window.AdMob.plugins.showAd(false); }">Hide Ad</button>
        </div>
```

phonegap run android

Comment: Is it not: window.plugins.AdMob.showAd(true); i.e. switch the order of plugins and AdMob...

Comment: There's still no detailed code-based answer for this question, that's the reason for the bounty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This admob plugin works with google play sdk: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob . Check readmes in main folder AND in subfolders for details.

Comment: I spent a couple of hours trying this solution, and the instructions are not very good.

Comment: Works for me. Also, the readme for android has just been updated. It has now a simplified installation method. Maybe try this one.

Comment: That is a good simplification. However I am getting a black box with no adverts, I have read it could be down to my pub ID, however I have literally just copied it from google admob. Any suggestions? P.s. thanks for the link to the updated instructions, I was starting to investigate other ad providers

Comment: Im getting the alert AdMob plugin not loaded

Comment: For publisherId you have to use AD unit ID actually (ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/xxxxxxxxxxxxx). Dont't know why you're getting alert though, I haven't tested simplified method yet. Maybe you need to manually add reference to google-play-services_lib in project.properties and update lib-project (see manual setup instructions 2. and https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Comment: does this approach support latest cordova: 3.5.0-0.2.4, I have imported it, debuged it through chrome, but no ad is visible in my app.

Answer (score 3):

Review (2016). In order to use it with npm sources, if you are using cordova CLI version, you can add your plugin with:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-admob
```

If you are integrating with phonegap build, as they don't support gradle (at this moment), you should add this tag in your config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="phonegap-admob" source="npm"/>
```

There are full set-up instructions and wiki [here](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog. So that you can ad admob in your Phonegap app without any plugin.
http://phonegapguru.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-add-native-admob-ad-in.html?m=1